# Quadratic form, from independence to normality

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-theory, normal-distribution, independence, quadratic-forms

Suppose we have a $k$-dimensional random variable $x$, and for any given idempotent matrix $A$, $x'Ax$ and $x'(I-A)x$ are independent to each other. Is $x$ normally distributed?

Far as I know, for $2$-dimensional $x$ and idempotent and symmetric $A$, once $Ax$ is always independent to $(I-A)x$,
$x$ must have the $2$-dimensional normal distribution. And I think it's also true for higher dimensions.

I know the fact that an idempotent matrix can always be diagonalized by an orthogonal matrix to a diagonalized matrix with eigenvalues $0,1$. But I know little about the quadratic form.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"I know the fact that an idempotent matrix can always be diagonalized by an orthogonal matrix"*-- this is not true as it implies $A$ is symmetric and idempotence alone does not imply symmetry.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out it. I have made an edit. Actually it's the diagonal matrix with elements $0,1$ conjugated by a orthogonal matrix that interest me.

Comment: @Oolongmilktea Perhaps you mean symmetric idempotent matrix $A$.